# What exactly does a type inference provide for a class?

Tags: java

I've been reading up on type inferences in java and I understand how to define and instantiate classes with type inferences but I don't understand what the benefits of providing a type inference(s) are. Any info on the topic would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:
I'm talking about classes not methods. For example you would declare a class like this:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public MyClass() {...}

    ...
}
```

And then instantiate the class like this:

```
MyClass<String> myInstance = new MyClass<String>();
```

What would `MyClass` get from having the type `String` in that example?

Comment: [Type Inference Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

Comment: Makes it so you don't have to use `<SomeType>` and such all over the place by inferring the type (`SomeType`) from the type of the arguments provided.

Comment: If you love to write boilerplate code, then there are absolutely no benefits :). If you prefer to let the compiler infer generic types that are obvious then type inference is a great help

Comment: You are using the wrong words. You mean "type *parameters*" or generics. Type inference is something else.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: it ensures that a certain parameter is of a certain type.

take the method

```
public <T> doSomething(T argument){
   return argument;
}
```

Now you could call it with:

```
String s = doSomething("Hello World");
Integer i = doStomething(5);
Boolean b = doSomething(false);
```

But calls like this would be invalid:

```
String s = doSomething(3);
Integer i = doStomething(3.6);
Boolean b = doSomething("Hello");
```

In words: The type of the value to which you assign the methods return value will determine `<T>` - and then `T argument` needs to match that type.

Comment: i understand what it does for methods I just don't understand how I would use it at the class level.